# Aplicativo dando Crash em um botão dentro de um AlertDialog costumizado

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, listener, alertdialog

Estou trabalhando com Alert Dialogs e me apareceu um erro onde o aplicativo para de responder. O código à seguir se refere à um fragmento onde se está utilizando o Google Maps API, e significa que quando eu clicar em um marcador específico ele vai abrir um AlertDialog. Até aí tudo bem, o problema começa quando eu tento referenciar um botão do XML do AlertDialog, com a id **ConcluirAdd**, porém ao colocar estas funções, quando o GPSActivity (o container do Fragmento) é iniciado, o aplicativo "Crasha". Agradeço à qualquer reposta que possa servir de utilidade à estas funções.
Vale lembrar que estou usando o Android Studio, e o problema está relacionado à um "OnClickListener" dentro de um AlertDiolog.

Java:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            GPSActivity.ShowToast(marker.getTitle());

            if(marker.getTitle().contains("Inserir")) {
                GPSActivity.finLatLngGet = marker.getPosition();

                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                View mView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_window, null);

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                Log.e("Activity", getActivity().getComponentName().toString());
                dialog.show();
//Erro à partir da linha abaixo
                Button btn_fin = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.concluirAdd);
                btn_fin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        GPSActivity.ShowToast("Deu Certo");
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Adicionar Marcador"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Título"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Mensagem"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:entries="@array/event_name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/concluirAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Finalizar" />
```

Erro:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.axis.appname, PID: 26078
>                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                          at com.axis.appname.MapFragment$1.onMarkerClick(MapFragment.java:266)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$2.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzu$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>                                                                          at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bz.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:84)
>                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.dd.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:292)
>                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:242)
>                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.m.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:4070)
>                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.af.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:611)
>                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.df.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:236)
>                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:189)
>                                                                          at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.i.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:132)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lugar de `getActivity()` use a `View`. Veja um exemplo:

```
Button btn_fin = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.concluirAdd);
```